# Ant Design Layout Component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a very basic implementation of ant design in a react project. I used `create-react-app` and have went through the suggested steps detailed in the antd documentation.

The problem i have is resizing the `Content` section of the `Layout` component. Currently, even though my `Dragger` component is wrapped within `Content` component, it is appearing below it. The `Content` component is represented by the Grey area on the screen. Attempts at resizing it using styling have not yielded desired results.

Here is the [code pen](https://codepen.io/hysi/pen/dyyrNKR?&editable=true&editors=001#anon-signup). Im simply trying to ensure that the Upload box is located within the Content section, and not below it.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped the `Dragger` component in a div that is [absolutely positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) in the center of the body, so it's disregarding the regular content flow.  If you remove that inline CSS it will behave as you'd expect.

Comment: Yes i want this positioned in there, just within the content section? Is there a correct way to do this so that i can drag the entire content section of my layout down with it. I'm trying to create a static layout per page and render different content

Comment: Just remove the style prop from your container div.

Comment: Yea i did that -- here is a new [codepen](https://codepen.io/hysi/pen/dyyrNKR?editors=0010). This essentially just bumps everything to the top, which is unwanted. I want the content section to consume about 80% of my screen, regardless if there is actually any content within, and the header and footer sections to contain the remaining 20%

Comment: It is inside the content div.. what exactly are you looking to accomplish? If you want different styles, you will have to add them.

Comment: I'd look into [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).

Comment: This is just what i needed. Thanks!